# .NET MAUI - Connecting Windows Tablet and Use it as a debugging device for windows platform

Tags: asp.net, maui

I need some help.

If an external android device can be configured as debugging for android platform, how about windows platform?

How do I setup my tablet running windows 10 as an external device for debugging?

Specially testing out SwipeView, it does not support mouse swipes, so I need to test it out on my windows tablet device.

There is no mentioning of this in the documentations.

Comment: In terms of docs, you can refer to [Wired-Debugging](https://tomsoderling.github.io/Wired-Debugging-on-Surface/) and also similar to UWP, you can go through [Deploying and debugging UWP apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/debug-test-perf/deploying-and-debugging-uwp-apps).